# What are the allowed values for commandName in a launchSettings.json profile?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am trying to set up a custom launchSettings.json profile that runs the executable specified by the executablePath and commandLineArgs arguments.

However, it requires me to pick a value for commandName in order for F5 to work. IIS and Project both work but they seem to do the conventional things.

- What other options of commandName are available?
- Is there another way to build a fully custom profile?

```
    {
        "profiles": {
            "Custom": {
                "commandName": // what should this be?,
                "executablePath": "mycustomexecutable.exe",
                "commandLineArgs": "my custom args"
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: it seems that another option is "executable", but this causes VS to try and debug that executable. In my case I want to run a shell executable which will perform some setup and then ask VS to attach to the currently-running process.

Comment: The names do not matter they are just tags which Visual Studio uses to allow you to pick which setting to launch when you hit debug....

Comment: @JohnPeters I believe you're thinking of the profile name, not the commandName. I'll update to include a sample profile to show what I mean.